# Minimize windows, application startup

Tags: vbscript, minimize

Is there a way to minimize all windows automatically when launching an application?

I tried to call a .vbs file with the content above:

```
Set shell = wscript.CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Shell.MinimizeAll
```

But doing this, application is minimized too.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's no way to do that, only to minimize the whole application or not as you've found. Some particular applications may have a COM interface that allows it.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this minimizes the windows, but it will probably satisfy your requirement:

```
set objShell = CreateObject("shell.application")
objShell.ToggleDesktop
```

This is equivalent to clicking the show desktop button.

Or as just extending your code:

```
shell.ToggleDesktop
```

Edit: Nevermind... this does the same thing as your code above. But why not just run this and then display your window? For instance, if it is your app... call the vbs and then display the window. Or if you have no control over the app, call it from a .bat file and run this vbs then your program.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, I'm trying your suggestions. The application will be burned to a CD-ROM with an autorun.inf file. It will call the .bat The .bat will call for first, the .vbs and then launch the application. I'll use this for a while.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is first minimize all applications or toggle the desktop; THEN (perhaps even after a delay) open your application.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).